# Grafana Loki cant Query pod logs

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki

I want to do a simple POC to see how Grafana/Loki works and how I can use it to query my pod logs.

I have the following set up:
I have created a local kind cluster using the following config (k8s version v1.27.1):

```yaml
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
- role: worker
- role: worker
```

I then installed grafana (via prometheus helm) and loki using the following commands:

```bash
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
helm repo update
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
# get the UI admin password
k get secret prometheus-grafana -o jsonpath="{.data.admin-password}" | base64 --decode ; echo

#install loki
helm repo add grafana https://grafana.github.io/helm-chartshelm repo update
helm repo update
helm install --values values.yaml loki grafana/loki --set loki.auth_enabled=false

# values.yaml content
# minio:
#   enabled: true

# port forward to access the UI
kubectl port-forward deployment/prometheus-grafana 3000
```

afterwards I have added the the loki url `http://loki-gateway` from the Grafana UI
[Grafana UI add Loki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRnIG.png)

I then created a simple app to verify that I can query its logs, using the following config:

```yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo-app
  labels:
    app: app1
    component: foo1
spec:
  containers:
  - name: foo-app
    image: hashicorp/http-echo:0.2.3
    args:
    - "-text=hello from namespace default"
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: foo1
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    component: foo1
  ports:
  # Default port used by the image
  - port: 5678
```

When I access the app I can see the logs from `kubectl logs foo-app`:

```
2023/06/13 14:30:27 Server is listening on :5678
2023/06/13 14:30:43 localhost:3001 127.0.0.1:60142 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 29 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0" 65.864µs
2023/06/13 14:30:45 localhost:3001 127.0.0.1:60142 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 29 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0" 56.885µs
2023/06/13 14:30:46 localhost:3001 127.0.0.1:60142 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 29 "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0" 9.868µs
```

I'm unable to see its logs from Loki. It seems to me that Loki cant see that this pod exists.
[Grafana Loki UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nDrC.png)

I think this might be related to Loki permissions, but looking at the Cluster roles it seems that the permissions are there. What else I might be missing?

I have tried to recreate the custom application without any success. I have also tried adding more permissions to the Loki ClusterRole again with no luck

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it using the `promtail` helm chart to send logs to loki using this config:

```yaml
config:
  clients:
    - url: http://loki-gateway/loki/api/v1/push
      tenant_id: 1
  snippets:
    pipelineStages:
      - docker: {}
```